# checkbox value is not displaying

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following code

```
   <tr>
<td align=left colspan=6><table border="0">
  <tr>
      <td><font class="body_text"> windows: <input name="pro1" id="products0" type="checkbox" value="5" test="5"></td>

        <td><font class="body_text"> cpu: <input name="pro2" id="products1" type="checkbox" value="2" test="2"></td>

        <td><font class="body_text"> keyboard: <input name="pro3" id="products2" type="checkbox" value="3" test="3"></td>

        <td><font class="body_text"> mouse: <input name="pro4" id="products3" type="checkbox" value="4" test="4"></td>


  </tr>
```

and I am trying to get the value of first check box in the DOM

```
if(document.form.products[0].checked == true) alert(document.form.products[0].value);
```

this gives me an alert but value is undefined.

thanks

Comment: Your PHP code is irrelevant and also in the way. Please show the code that your PHP produces, because _that_ is what the browser is looking at.

Comment: -1 for using tables and the `font` element in a non-semantic manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the controls are in a form with the id `form` (which isn't a good name), then the problem is that you don't have any controls with the name "products", but you are trying to access a control with that name.

Either change `products` to the name (or id) of the control you want (and since the names are unique, get rid of `[0]`) or change the names of all the checkboxes to `products`.

You also have a number of other problems which aren't directly related to this issue.

1. You are using `<font>` which is deprecated, presentational and rubbish
2. You aren't using `<label>` which is needed for accessibility (including making the click target for checkboxes bigger than tiny)
3. You <del>appear to be</del> *are* using tables for layout
4. `form` is too generic an id
5. Better style is `document.form.ID_OF_FORM.elements.NAMES_OF_CHECKBOXES[0]`
6. The `checked` property is a boolean, `== true` is redundant

Answer (score 0):

You have all your inputs with the same `id` attribute. This is syntactically illegal and also likely the cause of your trouble. Make each one unique.